# Displaying indicators below the average in the list

Tags: python, list, file, field, average

I am newbie in python

My program should output less than average weight, but for some reason nothing happens

```
def minavg():
    print("\n" * 5)
    print(" List of passengers with baggage weight below average:")
    data = []
    from tabulate import tabulate
    with open('list.txt','r', encoding="utf-8") as f: 
        total = 0
        count = 0
        data = []
        for line in f:
            field1, field2, field3, field4 = line.split(',')
            total += int(field4)
            count += 1
    result = round(total / count)
    a = int(result)
    b = int(field4)
    if a < b in line.split():
            data.append(list(map(str.strip, line.split(',')))) 
    print(tabulate(data, tablefmt='grid', headers=('Name', 'ID', 'Place', 'Baggage Weight')))
```

The list itself:

```
Petter, 2345, 13, 12
Anna, 2243, 23, 31
Bob, 9112, 1, 0
Sergey, 9921, 32, 8
Jine, 1230, 5, 0
Tom, 9222, 6, 1
```

In theory, the code should display the names of people whose weight (last line) is less than 10 (since 10 is the average number).

[what shows cmd:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tudC2.png)

Comment: Did you ever call that function? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I got information output. But when I tried to find the minimum from the average, everything stopped working.

Comment: can you share what console is showing @TermalQuake

Comment: @YashMehta https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/922171768486113283/1055459641573769306/image.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes made:-**

```
(1) `if a < b in line.split():` -> `if a>b:` coz a storing the average value and b storing line value.
(2) Remove the function min avg.
(3) Redundancy of `data` initialization removed [i.e you have initialize data again when you have open file.].
```

**Code:-**

```
from tabulate import tabulate
print(" List of passengers with baggage weight below average:")
data = []
with open('list.txt','r', encoding="utf-8") as f: 
    total = 0
    count = 0
    for line in f:
        field1, field2, field3, field4 = line.split(',')
        total += int(field4)
        count += 1
        result = round(total / count)
        a = int(result)
        b = int(field4)
        if a>b:
          data.append(list(map(str.strip, line.split(',')))) 
print(tabulate(data, tablefmt='grid', headers=('Name', 'ID', 'Place', 'Baggage Weight')))
```

**Output:-**

```
List of passengers with baggage weight below average:
+--------+------+---------+------------------+
| Name   |   ID |   Place |   Baggage Weight |
+========+======+=========+==================+
| Bob    | 9112 |       1 |                0 |
+--------+------+---------+------------------+
| Sergey | 9921 |      32 |                8 |
+--------+------+---------+------------------+
| Jine   | 1230 |       5 |                0 |
+--------+------+---------+------------------+
| Tom    | 9222 |       6 |                1 |
+--------+------+---------+------------------+
```

Updated query:-
**Is there a way to sort the weight in ascending order?**

just sort before the print statement..

```
data.sort(key= lambda x:x[3]) #Baggage weight in ascending order
print(tabulate(data, tablefmt='grid', headers=('Name', 'ID', 'Place', 'Baggage Weight')))
```

**Output:-**

```
 List of passengers with baggage weight below average:
+--------+------+---------+------------------+
| Name   |   ID |   Place |   Baggage Weight |
+========+======+=========+==================+
| Bob    | 9112 |       1 |                0 |
+--------+------+---------+------------------+
| Jine   | 1230 |       5 |                0 |
+--------+------+---------+------------------+
| Tom    | 9222 |       6 |                1 |
+--------+------+---------+------------------+
| Sergey | 9921 |      32 |                8 |
+--------+------+---------+------------------+
```

**for descending** try- `data.sort(key= lambda x:x[3],reverse=True)`.